How to reuse objects in python in different classes in different files
I have an OrderManager class in one file that handles sending orders. There's also a PositionManager class that calculates the best price for maximum profit using various algorithms and then sends the order through the OrderManager. For different clients, there are separate instances of the PositionManager running different algorithms.
What I need is for all PositionManager instances for the same client to share the same OrderManager instance.
I tried using a singleton for the OrderManager, but it's not working properly when there are multiple PositionManager instances.

You will need a [mcve] for this
